# Firebase getreference() vrs getreference(value)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase contains different data trees like Users, hobbies, class, scores etc. I want to get values from two  sets of data “Users” and “hobbies”.

What is the best way to get values from the two tables?

Should I use `firebaseDatabase.getReference()` and then

```
dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(“name”).getValue().toString();
dataSnapshot.child("hobbies ").child(“track”).getValue().toString();
```

Or do I have to `firebaseDatabase.getReference(“Users”)` and `firebaseDatabase.getReference(“hobbies”);`

Since I noticed that `firebaseDatabase.getReference()` seem to refer to all data including the ones that are not needed(class, scores etc). Will this cause the app to slow down or does it have any implications?

Answer (score 2):

If you attach a listener to a `DatabaseReference`, it will download/read all data under that reference. So if you attach a listener to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`, you are reading all data in your database.

If you only need a subset of all data in your app, it's more efficient to only load that data. This means that you'll need to attach a separate listener to each branch of data that you need.